# Compare a selected date against a table column or an array of dates produced from MySQL query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, ejs

I have a page that looks like this:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is to compare "Holiday Date:" selection against the row values in "Date" columns from the table below it. I've tried using a code like this:

```
function dateChk(){
        var dt1 = document.getElementById('PHDate').value;
        var dt2 = document.getElementById('phdateadd').value;
            if (dt1 == dt2) {
               alert("This date already assigned, please try again.");
               document.getElementById('phdateadd').value = 0;
         }
 }
```

But this only work on the first row. Then I thought of doing array like:

```html
<input id="phdateadd" name="phdateadd" type="date" onchange="myFunction()" required>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var dates= ["2021-01-01", "2021-02-12", "2021-02-13", "2021-04-02", "2021-05-01", 
                        "2021-05-13", "2021-05-14", "2021-05-26", "2021-05-30", "2021-05-31", 
                        "2021-07-06", "2021-07-20", "2021-08-10", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-16", 
                        "2021-10-02", "2021-10-19", "2021-11-04", "2021-12-25"];

function checkDate(date) {
  return date == document.getElementById("phdateadd").value;
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dates.find(checkDate);
  var chk = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  
  if ( chk != "undefined" ) {
        alert("This date already assigned, please try again.");
        document.getElementById("phdateadd").value = 0;}
}
</script>
```

This does work however I have to specify all the dates from that column as array. I have this idea of passing data from MySQL query with the date values formatted similar to the array but it doesn't seem to recognize. This is the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('["',GROUP_CONCAT(phdate SEPARATOR '", "'),'"]') As arrdate FROM table1;

which returns

["2021-01-01", "2021-02-12", "2021-02-13", "2021-04-02", "2021-05-01", "2021-05-13", "2021-05-14",
 "2021-05-26", "2021-05-30", "2021-05-31", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-20", "2021-08-10", "2021-08-31",
 "2021-09-16", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-19", "2021-11-04", "2021-12-25"]
```

So, I took that result and show it in the page:

```
<% phDates.forEach((phDates, index) => { %>
        <tr><td><p id="phdates" name="phdates" value="<%= phDates.arrdate %>"><%= phDates.arrdate %>
            <% }) %></p><p id="demo" name="demo">b</p><br><p id="demo1" name="demo1">a</p></td></tr>

<script>
var dates = document.getElementById("phdates").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dates;
</script>
```

[image]

As you can see `arrdate` values that comes from the MySQL query and `demo` is showing similar format. The `demo` value is different when I specify the array in `var dates` (like in my snippet above):
[image]

If I purposely make the MySQL return data as above though it still doesn't recognize it. I think if this method is workable, I don't even need to compare the selected date to the column in the table. I did a test using `$( "div" ).toArray()` but I can't get it to work either.

I think this could be the straight forward solution for me but I'm wondering how do I format the MySQL result value to correspond with the correct javascript array format? Or leave the MySQL output as it is and convert that value to javascript array compatible value. I can't help to think that the solution might be simple but I've been looking for a couple of days and I haven't found any.

Comment: your snippet works nicely...

Comment: yes @AntonyJack but that is if I specify (hardcode) the array. I wanted to use a list of dates data from MySQL query result.. in short, I just want a dynamic array of values rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: What's with the `<%`...`%>` tags? Are you using ASP or PHP, or some other server-side language? It also looks like your loop to output the dates is generating multiple `<p>` tags with `id="phdates"`, which is illegal HTML (`id`s must be unique).

Comment: @kmoser updated tags. I didn't include the `node.js` and `ejs` (`<%...%>`) tags because I thought my question was about "how to output from MySQL query to html and being recognize as javascript array". Sorry about that. My working code is exactly like in the snippet. Others were just additional testing I've done and I don't have any `<p>` (or other) tags with duplicate `id` in my code.

Comment: Since you already fetch the data to display them to your table, there is no need to fetch them again in the form of an array. You're using static element IDs inside a loop, which is terrible; change these IDs with class names. In order for your `dateChk` to work, you'll need to replace the IDs of `PHDate` elements to classes and then inside `dateChk` you query all `PHDate` classes elements (*using `document.querySelectorAll('.PHDate')`*) and compare each date until you find a match or the loop ends.

Comment: @ChristosLytras , that was what my initial plan is but I just couldn't wrap my head around how to get them from the table column. I did find `document.querySelectorAll()` example somewhere but haven't tried it yet. I'll might try it later but I'm interested in @Lajos answer at the moment because it seems like its a continuation of my second attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a straight-forward solution. Let's start our thought process from your query, which is not very far from the solution (this is not good yet, but it's close-enough to start our thought process from it):

```
SELECT CONCAT('["',GROUP_CONCAT(phdate SEPARATOR '", "'),'"]') As arrdate FROM table1;
```

You intend here to convert your data into a JSON-like string. Naturally, you could call `JSON.parse` or `eval` with value assignment on this result, but I recommend a much more elegant way:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(phdate SEPARATOR ',') As dates FROM table1;
```

The above will contain a string with dates separated by comma. Assuming that you get this into a JS variable called myDates, you can just call:

```
myDates.split(",")
```

```js
let myDates = '2021-01-13,2021-02-02,2021-03-04'; //results from db

console.log(myDates.split(','));
```

Comment: That's it! I knew that its as simple as that. I have changed my query and uses `split(,)` and it works!

Comment: @fadlikidd I'm happy your problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Generate either of these in the `WHERE` clause of SQL:

```
arrdate IN ("2021-01-01", "2021-02-12", "2021-02-13")

FIND_IN_SET(arrdate, "2021-01-01,2021-02-12,2021-02-13")
```

The performance of the first *may* benefit from a suitable `INDEX`; the second won't.

If you are trying to check whether any of several dates (or other value) is found in any of a second set of dates -- This is not directly available in MySQL.  Split one list (or the other list) into rows in a table, then use `IN` or `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Or use application code.