# How to run a comparison between local date state and dates in database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I'm trying to build an availability calendar to where users can select a date and a time and fill out some information where it gets submitted to the database.

I got all the functionality working but I've run into the hardest obstacle that I can't seem to solve.

I need to figure out how I can run a comparison between my local state data that has hard coded dates, and availability date times in my database.

I want the current functionality to behave as follows:

If a user selects a date, I need to run a query to select that date in the database and run a condition. If any of these date times are already in the database block out that time available for that current date. If there are multiple time-slots taken up for that specific day, block all times that were already scheduled for that day.

**Example:**

A user has already scheduled an appointment for today at 10:00 AM (that appointment is already in the database). A different user tries to schedule the same appointment for today at 10:00AM. Therefore, that timeslot should be blocked (on the client) and not available to that user and they'll need to choose a different time. If a date time isn't in the database, the user can schedule that date and time and it'll insert that data into the database.

I have a lot of code so I'll try to show a simple scenario of what I'm trying to achieve:

ReactJS (Client)

```js
// Hard Coded Local Time Slots

let timeSlots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    dayType: "Morning",
    times: [
      {
        Time: "T16:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
      {
        Time: "T17:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
      {
        Time: "T18:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    dayType: "Afternoon",
    times: [
      {
        // lunch
        Time: "T19:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: true,
      },
      {
        Time: "T20:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
      {
        Time: "T21:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
      {
        Time: "T22:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
      {
        Time: "T23:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    dayType: "Evening",
    times: [
      // dinner
      {
        Time: "T24:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: true,
      },
      {
        Time: "T01:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
      {
        Time: "T02:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
      {
        Time: "T03:00:00.000Z",
        IsBlock: false,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const Voipcall = () => {

  const [scheduleData, setscheduleData] = useState({
    date: "",
    actualDateStart: "",
    actualDateEnd: "",
    startTime: "",
    endTime: "",
    fullName: "",
    resident: "",
    communicationMethod: "In Person",
    email: "",
    phone: "(1  )    -    ",
    description: "",
  });
  const [scheduleDataError, setscheduleDataError] = useState({
    fullNameError: "",
    residentError: "",
    communicationMethodError: "",
    emailError: "",
    phoneError: "",
    descriptionError: "",
  });
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [activeStep, setactiveStep] = useState(0);

  const getStepContent = (step) => {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <div className="col-lg-8">
            <FullCalendar
              plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
              initialView="dayGridMonth"
              dateClick={handleDateClick}
              selectable={true}
            />
          </div>
        );
      case 1:
      // Part where I'm stuck on, I need to check for availability in my database,
      // and if there is availability allow the user to click the button,
      // if there isn't time available for that specific day,
      // set disabled to true
        return (
          <div
            className="col-lg-8 col-md-12 order-md-last text-center"
            id="time-blocks"
          >
            {timeSlots.map((data, i) => (
              <div className="timeslot-container mt-4" key={i}>
                <p className="pb-3 font-weight-bold">{data.dayType}</p>
                {data.times.map((times, j) => (
                  <Button
                    variant={times.IsBlock ? "outline-dark" : "outline-primary"}
                    disabled={times.IsBlock ? true : false}
                    className="d-block my-3 mx-auto"
                    style={{ width: "150px" }}
                    onClick={(e) => selectAppointment(e, times.Time)}
                    key={j}
                    value={Moment(scheduleData.date + times.Time).format(
                      "h:mm a"
                    )}
                  >
                    {Moment(scheduleData.date + times.Time).format("h:mm a")}
                  </Button>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
  };

  const handleDateClick = (arg) => {
    let newDate = arg.dateStr;

    setscheduleData({
      ...scheduleData,
      date: newDate,
    });
  };


  const selectAppointment = (e, rawTime) => {
    let formatTime = Moment(scheduleData.date + rawTime)
      .add(1, "hours")
      .format("h:mm a");

    let formatDate = scheduleData.date + rawTime;

    setscheduleData({
      ...scheduleData,
      startTime: e.target.value,
      endTime: formatTime,
      actualDateStart: formatDate,
      actualDateEnd: Moment(formatDate).add(1, "hours").toISOString(),
    });
  };

  const scheduleAppointment = () => {

    if (
      scheduleData.fullName === "" ||
      scheduleData.resident === "" ||
      scheduleData.communicationMethod === "" ||
      scheduleData.email === "" ||
      scheduleData.phone === "" ||
      scheduleData.startTime === "" ||
      scheduleData.endTime === ""
    ) {
      console.log("submission false");
    } else {
      let insertData = {
        RoleId: undefined ? "3" : "3",
        FullName: scheduleData.fullName,
        Resident: scheduleData.resident,
        CommunicationMethod: scheduleData.communicationMethod,
        Email: scheduleData.email,
        Phone: scheduleData.phone,
        StartTime: scheduleData.actualDateStart,
        EndTime: scheduleData.actualDateEnd,
        Description:
          scheduleData.description === undefined
            ? null
            : scheduleData.description,
        DateCreated: Moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"),
      };

      // This inserts the data into the database
      const insertSchedule = Scheduleservice.insertSchedule(insertData);

      // Clear all data and fields
      setscheduleData({
        date: "",
        startTime: "",
        endTime: "",
        fullName: "",
        resident: "",
        communicationMethod: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "(1  )    -    ",
        description: "",
      });
      setscheduleDataError({
        fullNameError: "",
        residentError: "",
        communicationMethodError: "",
        emailError: "",
        phoneError: "",
        descriptionError: "",
      });
      setactiveStep(0);
      setShow(true);
    }
  };

  const steps = getSteps();
  return null;
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Voipcall);
```

MYSQL back-end

```js
var db = require("../dbconnection");

var schedule = {
  // This query will grab all appointments and time-slots that were scheduled for that specific day based on date selection from the user
    selectSchedule: function (data, callback) {
db.query(
  "select Id, StartTime, EndTime, IsBlock from schedule where date(DateCreated) = ?", [data.date],
  callback
);
  },
};

module.exports = schedule;
```

Comment: this problem becomes so much easier if you store your time slots in the database instead of hardcoding them

Comment: So if I store it in the database, I'm assuming under a separate table? How would I know to select only available times? Right now I have a schedule table but I guess I need a separate table with a foreign key I'm assuming?

Comment: You don't need to wait for the user select date only then you execute a query to check. It's better if you can already show unavailable date/time (usually a greyed out-unable to select)  from the selector. You mentioned that _"If a date time isn't in the database"_ but, your query condition is `where date(DateCreated) = ?`. It doesn't check for `time`. What  time that user can select? By 30 minutes interval? 1 hour interval?

Comment: I think I need to modify my query and table structure. I probably need two tables. 1 for data that gets inserted into the database and another table that shows available times. The hard coded times are in my code but I think I need to put it into a separate table. I'm just having trouble getting the query together to where if a time is already booked for a given day, make it unavailable in the UI. The time slot intervals are 1 hour so for example, if someone books for 10:00am it'll run from 10:00am to 11:00am

Comment: I don't think you need another table. You just query the existing table. You can do something like, execute a query on page load to return `date+time` that's already in the table then your front-end code will take that information and disables the `date+time` combination in the selector. I'm not sure if that is easy to do on `reactjs` though, I myself struggle to implement the idea in `nodejs`. I did [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694883/compare-a-selected-date-against-a-table-column-or-an-array-of-dates-produced-fro) about it before, not sure if it's similar to yours.